# Ping Federate Clustering HA for Admin Console

Tags: high-availability, pingfederate

I was working on a PoC where Ping Federate needs to be in High Availability mode. The clustering documentation provided by ping [[link]](https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/ix_m_downloadDocumentation/page/PF63ServerClusteringGuide.pdf) specifies how to cluster runtime servers and mentions that only one Admin Console should be present. How to achieve HA if Admin Console goes down due to some issue?

Edit: Using PingFederate 8.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple console instances are not supported within PingFederate clusters.

If one has a "mandate" from the business to have two consoles, then I would use an external directory synchronization tool to synchronize the /pingfederate directory on a regular basis (on the half hour, maybe). There's no need to synch the /pingfederate/log and /pingfederate/work directories. I would also exclude the pingfederate/bin/run.properties file (so that the proper IP addresses can be set in it). Include the "spare" console's IP address in the Discovery line in the run.properties. Only one of the consoles can be live at any given time - if a second one starts while the other is running, the second one will see the other, and shut down.

Comment: In my scenario, the configuration replication in the new runtime instance is automated using pf-admin-api. I wanted to have a system where the admin console shouldn't be down while a new runtime instance is coming up else the new instance would be up and running but no configuration have been pushed to it. The above mentioned answer sorts out the issue.

Comment: As a point of clarification... In a PingFederate cluster, there are two types of nodes: `clustered_console` and `clustered_engine`. We commonly see **HA** deployments where there are multiple `clustered_engine`s in multiple datacenters (e.g., two in each of three DCs). If you lose the DC with the `clustered_console` in it, so what - you can continue to process authentications, you just can't make changes. One would hope that eventually the other DC comes back... But, if it doesn't, restore the directory from the offsite backup onto a new server, and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

While PingAccess does have clustered console, PingFederate currently does not.

Recommendation: Stop the PingFederate console service, backup the entire directory, and restart (or leave off unless configuration changes are needed).

Comment: Although the manual specifies there should be only 1 Administrative console instance and multiple runtime machines, can I use two instances behind a load balancer?

Comment: No - this isn't how the clustering in PingFederate works. Incidentally, the reasoning for the way it works is because the admin console doesn't actually do any "real" work, beyond being an interface to make changes.